# LinkFinder.find fails to work in webcrawler app

Tags: c#

Wrote code as the start to a web crawler that scrapes links from webpage.

Following the instructions from this page:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html

I seem to get an error that LinkFinder cannot be found?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebCrawler
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient url = new WebClient();
        String initialLink = url.DownloadString("http://www.FAKEADDRESS.org.uk/");

        for (LinkItem i in LinkFinder.find(initialLink))
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(initialLink);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is LinkFinder class in your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinkFinder` is a class that is included in the code at that URL you provided.  Make sure you also copy that class into your project in some way (a file by itself, in another file, whatever).